# asp.net: add attribute to headers th

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, attributes

I changed a gridview's header to ... with

```
    Sub MakeAccessible(ByVal grid As GridView)
    If grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        grid.UseAccessibleHeader = True
        grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        grid.HeaderRow.CssClass = ""
        'grid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I need to add attributes to the th tags like th xyz=boom. How to do so?

Thx a lot for your help and interest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `Attributes.Add`

Example

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("class", "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute to the header row by adding by adding the following to your sub

```
grid.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Attributes.Add("xyz", "boom")
```